# c++ How do I get data out of a function without using the return?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. I'd like to use a pointer but I'm not sure how to deal with scope. By the way, foo() and bar() are in different files. Bar() gets "calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In" just fine, but how do I get bar() "calculation_I_Want" too?

```
int foo()
{
    int calculation_I_Want = 2 + 2;
    int calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In = 5 + 5;
    return calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In;
}

int bar()
{

    int some_Other_Variable_I_Am_Not_Interested_In = foo();

    /*How do I get calculation_I_Want's data from here without using foo's return? 
      Can I use a pointer? if so, how do I deal with scope?*/
}
```

Comment: pass a `&variable` in and then assign

Comment: Pass a variable-by-reference in as a parameter to your function.

Comment: Or change foo() to return a struct containing the results of both calculations.

Comment: Either pass a variable in by reference, or pointer. If you just want to return multiple values, however, use `std::tuple` or `std::pair`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest doing this in a different way. Split the logic up into separate functions and call the piece you need:

```
int foo_part1()
{
    int calculation_I_Want = 2 + 2;
    return calculation_I_Want;
}

int foo()
{
    int calculation_I_Want = foo_part1();
    int calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In = 5 + 5;
    return calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In;
}

int bar()
{

    int some_Other_Variable_I_Am_Not_Interested_In = foo_part1();

    /*How do I get calculation_I_Want's data from here without using foo's return? 
      Can I use a pointer? if so, how do I deal with scope?*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To *simulate multiple return values* in C++ you can:

1. Pass parameters by non-const reference, modifying them in function's body

   ```
   void foo(int& calculation_I_Want, int& calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In)
   {
       calculation_I_Want = 2 + 2;
       calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In = 5 + 5;
   }
   ```
2. Pass parameters by non-const pointer, modifying them in functions body. Don't forget to check for `null` pointers.

   ```
   void foo(int* calculation_I_Want, int* calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In)
   {
       if(calculation_I_Want)
           calculation_I_Want = 2 + 2;
       if(calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In)
           calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In = 5 + 5;
   }
   ```
3. You can return an object of new type (`struct` or `class`), containing those variables:

   ```
   struct CalculationResults
   {
       int calculation_I_Want;
       int calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In;
   };

   CalculationResults foo()
   {
       CalculationResults res;
       res.calculation_I_Want = 2 + 2;
       res.calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In = 5 + 5;
       return res;
   }
   ```
4. You can return `std::pair`, `std::tuple`

   ```
   std::pair<int, int> foo()
   {
       ....
       return std::make_pair(calculation_I_Want, calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In);
   }
   ```
5. You can return a container (`std::array`, `std::vector`, etc.)
6. You can stop fighting with bad code and refactor it. Most times you facing with such issues, when you've made a mistake designing your code. For example, your function `foo()` is capable of calculation of two numbers and you are only interested in one of them. That means that single responsibility principle is violated here, and you must split `foo` to two separate functions:

   ```
   int foo1()
   {
       return 2 + 2;

   }

   int foo2()
   {
       return 5 + 5;
   }
   ```

   Another way of refactoring is to separate data and/or behavior into separate type:

   ```
   class CalculationResults
   {
   public:
       // TODO: make private
       int calculation_I_Want;
       int calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In;

       CalculationResults()
       {
           calculation_I_Want = 2 + 2;
           calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In = 5 + 5;
       }
   };
   ```

   Those concepts are often used in languages where there is no possibility of mutating function parameters (for example, Java)

Comment: Nice summary. +1, especially for not mentioning smelly solutions like globals.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at an example:

```
void foo(int & result1, int & result2) {
    result1 = 2 + 2;
    result2 = 5 + 5;
}

int main() {
    int r1, r2;

    foo(r1, r2);
    printf("r1: %d\n", r1);
    printf("r2: %d\n", r2);
}
```

This will output:

```
r1: 4
r2: 10
```

Comment: that's a C style solution, not C++. it works, but not recommended.

Comment: I'd rather advise to use references e.g. `int& result1` or movable references like `AnyType&& result1`for c++. Pointers are equivalent more or less, but complicate everything unnecessarily.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's quite true. These should be references instead of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The code would look something like this:

```
int foo(int &referenceVar)
{
    referenceVar = 2 + 2;
    int calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In = 5 + 5;
    return calculation_I_am_Not_Interested_In;
}

void bar()
{

    int outputVar;
    int returnVar = foo(outputVar);
}
```

At the end of bar(), outputVar would have a value of 4 and returnVar would have a value of 10. This method of passing data is called "pass-by-reference."

Answer (score 0):

You can use globals, references, or passed in pointers.  Globals have lots of inherent problems associated with them (scalability in particular), but just to be complete:

foo.c:

```
int gValueOfInterest
int foo() {
    gValueOfInterest=1;
    ....
}
```

bar.c:

```
extern int gValueOfInterest;
bar() {
    int x=gValueOfInterest;
}
```

Another way is to use a reference to a variable:

foo.c:

```
foo(int &value) {
   value=gValueOfInterest;
   ...
}
```

bar.c:

```
bar() {
    int x;
    foo(x);
 }
```

Finally, if you're using C instead of C++, or if you prefer actual pointers, you can do:

foo.c:

```
foo(int *pValue) {
    *pValue=valueOfInterest
}
```

bar.c:

```
bar() {
   int x;
   foo(&x);
}
```

John